# Atomic Kotlin: InKeyword/Task4.kt: `val num = 0..9` does not work in `string[i] in num`

Tags: kotlin, range, atomic

I'm beginner to programming and learning Kotlin by a learning course: [Atomic Kotlin](https://www.atomickotlin.com/ebook/).
I'm solving an exercise and can't understand why a part of my code doesn't work.
I can see answer code in the course, but I'd like to know how to solve my problem.

### problem

I made `val num = 0..9` and use it in `wholeStringChecker()` so that `wholeStringChecker()` can return true to a String that has numbers(0 to 9) in it.
However, in the result of `main()`, `isValidIdentifier("name0")` gives `false` to `0`.
The course offers Answer code and I can understand the code, but I'd like to understand the cause of my code's result.

### -exercise description written in the couese

Write a function that checks whether its String parameter is a valid identifier.  A valid identifier is a non-empty String that starts with a letter or underscore and consists of only letters, digits and underscores.
Use s.isEmpty() to check whether s is an empty String.

#### -whole code

```
// InKeyword/Task4.kt
package theInKeywordExercise4

fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean {
  val atoz = 'a'..'z'
  val AtoZ = 'A'..'Z'
  val num = 0..9

  fun emptyChecker(string: String): Boolean = string.isNotEmpty()
  fun initialChecker(string: String) :Boolean = string[0] in atoz || string[0] in AtoZ || string[0] in "_"
  fun wholeStringChecker(string: String): Boolean {
    var i = 0
    var counter = 0
    while (i <= string.lastIndex) {
      if (string[i] in atoz || string[i] in AtoZ || string[i] in num || string[i] in "_")
        println("true ${string[i]}")
      else {
        println("false ${string[i]}")
        counter++
      }
      i++
    }

    println("counter is $counter")
    if (counter > 0) {
      println("wholeStringChecker false")
      return false
    } else {
      println("wholeStringChecker true")
      return true
    }
  }

  return emptyChecker(s) && initialChecker(s) && wholeStringChecker(s)
}
fun main() {
  println(isValidIdentifier("name0"))
}
```

#### -result

```
true n
true a
true m
true e
false 0
counter is 1
wholeStringChecker false
false
```

*I expected 0 would get true, because I wrote `if (string[i] in atoz || string[i] in AtoZ || string[i] in num || string[i] in "_")` in `wholeStringChecker()`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. I get a "type inference failed" error at `string[i] in num`. Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: thank you for testing my code.
I got "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.", but my intelliJ compiled the code.
After I changed `val num = 0..9` into `val num = '0'..'9'`, the message disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
val num = '0'..'9'
```

You're looking at characters in a string, so you want to compare against characters, not integers.